# How to solo-mine bitcoins with bfgminer?

Tags: solo-mining, bfgminer, miner-configuration, mining-software

I'm completely new to Bitcoin, so my understanding of mining is still improving.

I downloaded [BFGMiner](https://en.bitcoin.it/wiki/BFGMiner), and now I would like to perform some solo mining.

(I would rather have it use my GPU, but if a CPU is noticeably easier than I'll go that route first.)

#### How can I use BFGMiner to perform solo mining?

- What arguments do I give to `bfgminer` on the command line?
- What information do I need, aside from my BitCoin wallet address?
- What other program(s), if any, do I need?

Again, I know very little about mining at this point, so please assume no prior knowledge -- all I know is basically my wallet address. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This article seems useful:

http://www.newslobster.com/random/how-to-get-started-using-your-gpu-to-mine-for-bitcoins-on-windows

Start with that and maybe later switch to using a pool.

Comment: That led me in the right direction to figure out how to use bfgminer, thanks!

Comment: Any chance you could copy the relavant information into this answer? Generally it's a good idea on SE sites to include information in the answer instead of just linking to somewhere else (remember, a link might be dead in a months time; information on SE should be self contained).

Comment: I realize that there's a lot to summarize in the linked article, but if the link breaks - this loses all context and value. Consider moving at least the most important take-aways from the linked article here? Otherwise, this is probably going to be removed (I hate coming off as 'thanks for giving us something, now please give us even more!' and that's not my intent. I'd do it myself, but I'm not sure how to do it compactly without copying it all over).

Comment: downvoted - link is dead. i would remove this as right answer too if i could as Eyal did not listen to comments above

Answer (score 3):

This is covered in the included [README](https://github.com/luke-jr/bfgminer/blob/bfgminer/README) document.

Comment: Please post the relevant part (or a summary) of the link to avoid link rot.

Comment: I would think avoiding StackExchange rot is a more likely problem here.

Comment: in the readme, search for solo mining